# How to make this VBA code relevant to a particular sheet(s) in my spreadsheet only?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, range

Thanks to a piece of code from Contextures my spreadsheet now allows for multiple selections in a particular drop down list; when you select another value, it will add it to the existing values in the cell - if you select a value listed in the cell again from the drop down, it will remove it from the sequence in the cell.

The code applies to two worksheets in my spreadsheet (well, probably to the entire spreadsheet, but the other sheets don't have drop downs), and the columns (Range) containing the drop down were initially in the same column on both sheets. However, due to some format changes in one of the two sheets, the relevant column with the drop down is now in different columns across the two sheets.

How can I either

1. adapt below code to apply to column X in sheet A and column Y in sheet B, or
2. apply this code twice to my spreadsheet; one time for sheet A and one time for sheet B - where I can then keep the code as-is, but change the column reference for the given sheet

I have looked into how to set up sheet references, but did not understand how to embed this in this piece of code. I also tried to understand how to make a piece of VBA relevant to one worksheet only, but that puzzles me even more - I don't understand how to apply this change to my current spreadsheet  I don't have experience with VBA - this is the second time I embed any VBA code - and have literally pieced this together based on tutorials and Q&A, so please "bear with me". Any help is welcome but I hope someone can help me with option 1 as I think it will be the easiest for me to apply!

THANKS!

```
Option Explicit
' Developed by Contextures Inc.
' www.contextures.com
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim lUsed As Long
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   'do nothing
Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  newVal = Target.Value
  Application.Undo
  oldVal = Target.Value
  Target.Value = newVal
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N:N")) Is Nothing Then
'<<ALTERNATIVE>>  If Target.Column = 14 Then
    If oldVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      If newVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
        lUsed = InStr(1, oldVal, newVal)
        If lUsed > 0 Then
            If Right(oldVal, Len(newVal)) = newVal Then
                Target.Value = Left(oldVal, Len(oldVal) - Len(newVal) - 2)
            Else
                Target.Value = Replace(oldVal, newVal & ", ", "")
            End If
        Else
            Target.Value = oldVal _
              & ", " & newVal
        End If
        
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your range is managed by this line of code:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N:N")) Is Nothing Then
```

To make it worksheet specific, you can write something like this:

```
If (Not Intersect(Target, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("N:N")) Is Nothing) 
    Or (Not Intersect(Target, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("P:P")) Is Nothing) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is linked to a worksheet change event and must be in the code for the sheet that it is relevant to. So copy it to sheet1 code (not a module) and it will only work for sheet1. If you put it in the workbook code page it may work for all sheets. So copy the code to the code for the specific sheets and modify the range to suit, if you do not specify the sheet in the code it will by default run on the page the code is linked to.

Answer (score 0):

### Worksheet Change for Multiple Worksheets

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExpandDropDown(ByVal Target As Range, ByVal ColumnId As Variant)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngDV As Range
    Dim rngCol As Range
    Dim oldVal As String
    Dim newVal As String
    Dim lUsed As Long
    
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub ' multiple cells intersecting
    
    Set ws = Target.Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngDV = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rngDV Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no matching cells
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no intersection
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngCol = ws.Columns(ColumnId)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rngCol Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' invalid 'ColumnId'
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Retrieve oldVal
    newVal = CStr(Target.Value)
    Application.Undo
    oldVal = CStr(Target.Value)
    Target.Value = newVal
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, rngCol) Is Nothing Then ' intersecting
        If oldVal <> "" Then
            If newVal <> "" Then
                lUsed = InStr(1, oldVal, newVal)
                If lUsed > 0 Then
                    If Right(oldVal, Len(newVal)) = newVal Then
                        Target.Value = Left(oldVal, Len(oldVal) _
                            - Len(newVal) - 2)
                    Else
                        Target.Value = Replace(oldVal, newVal & ", ", "")
                    End If
                Else
                    Target.Value = oldVal & ", " & newVal
                End If
            'Else ' do nothing because 'newVal = ""'
            End If
        ' Else ' do nothing because 'oldVal = ""'
        End If
    'Else ' do nothing because no intersection
    End If

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub
```

**Any Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`...**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     ExpandDropDown Target, "N" ' or 14, "X" or 24, "Y" or 25
End Sub
```